# rename filename by removing timestamp after file extension (.csv or .xlsx)

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I need a PowerShell script which will rename multiple files  from a folder

Sample Filenames:

```
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.csv.20190126_053415 
12345_ABC_20190125_1600.csv.20190126_0534156 
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx.20190126_0534156 
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx.20190126_0534156
```

Since the timestamp is not consistent I cannot use length.
The script should be able to identify the file extension (it can be input from users) and remove everything after that.

Desired Filenames:

```
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.csv
12345_ABC_20190125_1600.csv
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx
```

Currently, I have used length. Since timestamp length is not consistent I have to always modify the script.

My current code:

```
Write-Host

$Path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the file path'
$char = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input number of last character you want to remove'

Get-ChildItem "$Path" | rename-item -newname { $_.name.substring(0,$_.name.length-"$char") }

powershell -noexit
```

**How do I change filename with varying lenght?**

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [Path.ChangeExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, then remove the terminating dot character with the [String.TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
'1234_ABC_20190125_1600.csv.20190126_053415',
'12345_ABC_20190125_1600.csv.20190126_0534156',
'1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx.20190126_0534156',
'1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx.20190126_0534156' |
ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_, '').TrimEnd('.') }
```

**Output:**

```
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.csv
12345_ABC_20190125_1600.csv
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx
1234_ABC_20190125_1600.xlsx
```

**Update:**

Replace

```
Get-ChildItem "$Path" | ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_, '').TrimEnd('.') }
```

to

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '').TrimEnd('.')}`
```

Notice the [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6#risk-management-parameter-descriptions) parameter that displays a message that describes the effect of the command, instead of executing the command. To rename, delete this parameter.

**Update #2:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Filter *.????????_?????? |
  ForEach-Object {
    $n = $t = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '').TrimEnd('.')
    $p = Split-Path -Path $n -Parent
    $l = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($n)
    $x = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($n)
    $i = 1
    while( Test-Path -Path $t -PathType Any ) {
      $t = Join-Path -Path $p -ChildPath "${l}_${i}${x}"
      $i++
    }
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $t -WhatIf
  }
```

To rename, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter or rewrite it as `-WhatIf:$false`.

**Update #3:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
$type = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]
for() {
  $path = $type::InputBox('Enter the path of interest:', 'Path request')
  if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($path) ) { break }
  if( Test-Path -LiteralPath $path -PathType Container ) {
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -File -Filter *.????????_?????? |
      ForEach-Object {
        $n = $t = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '').TrimEnd('.')
        $p = Split-Path -LiteralPath $n
        $l = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($n)
        $x = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($n)
        $i = 1
        while( Test-Path -LiteralPath $t -PathType Any ) {
          $t = Join-Path -LiteralPath $p -ChildPath "${l}_${i}${x}"
          $i++
        }
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $t -WhatIf
      }
    $result = $type::MsgBox('Want to rerun the script again?',
                            'RetryCancel, Question', 'Request to rerun')
  } else {
    $result = $type::MsgBox(
                "The path entered is not valid.`nWant to re-enter the path?",
                'RetryCancel, Question', 'Request to re-enter'
              )
  }
  if( $result -eq 'Cancel' ) { break }
}
```

I think you can get rid of `-NoExit`.

**Update #4:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
$type = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]
for() {
  $path = $type::InputBox('Enter the path of interest:', 'Path request')
  if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($path) ) { break }
  if( Test-Path -LiteralPath $path -PathType Container ) {
    $result = $type::MsgBox("Do you want to rename?`nSelect Cancel to exit.",
                            'YesNoCancel, Question',
                            'Request of the value of the -WhatIf parameter')
    if( $result -eq 'Cancel' ) { break }
    $whatif = $result -eq 'No'
    $renamed = 0
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -File -Filter *.????????_?????? |
      ForEach-Object {
        $n = $t = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '').TrimEnd('.')
        $p = Split-Path -LiteralPath $n
        $l = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($n)
        $x = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($n)
        $i = 1
        while( Test-Path -LiteralPath $t -PathType Any ) {
          $t = Join-Path -LiteralPath $p -ChildPath "${l}_${i}${x}"
          $i++
        }
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $t -WhatIf:$whatif
        $renamed++
      }
    if( $whatif -or $renamed -eq 0 ) { $prompt = 'Nothing has been done' }
    else {
      if( $renamed -eq 1 ) { $prompt = '1 file was' }
      else { $prompt = "${renamed} files were" }
      $prompt = "${prompt} renamed"
    }
    $prompt = "${prompt}.`nWant to rerun the script again?"
    $result = $type::MsgBox($prompt, 'RetryCancel, Question', 'Request to rerun')
  } else {
    $result = $type::MsgBox(
                "The path entered is not valid.`nWant to re-enter the path?",
                'RetryCancel, Question', 'Request to re-enter'
              )
  }
  if( $result -eq 'Cancel' ) { break }
}
```

Added a request of the value of the `-WhatIf` parameter and displaying information about the number of renamed files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. File name also can have . before extension. Will the above solution work in that scenario?

Comment: @Rias, i didn't understand you mean. Can you please explain with some examples?

Comment: when I run the modified script it does not change the file name but in PowerShell console, I see the modified file name.                                      
Write-Host


$Path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the file path'




Get-ChildItem "$Path" | 
ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_, '').TrimEnd('.') }


powershell -noexit

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. The code works. But I have two questions: 1. When there is file with same name (after renaming) how can script handle this? For example, adding number (_1) at the end of the file. Example: 1234_ABC_20190125_1600_1.xlsx                                                                           
 2. Currently, I have powershell -noexit  so that console does not close but I want to add a command so that script auto executes again since the first line is host input, it will wait for the input from users. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rias, it took a little longer to do this :)

Comment: many many thanks for your help. currently, I have used powershell -noexit so that PowerShell does not close.
In addition,  I would like to add a bit of user functionality by adding an IF statement. IF user inputs "E" the command prompt will close or if the input "R" the script will rerun. is it possible?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated script, Andrei.                                                             
But unfortunately, the updated script throw errors if I run it 3 consecutive times. It can't rename the file and keeps looping.

Comment: @Rias, I think we didn’t consider the `-WhatIf` parameter. Check out update #4.